# Linux screencast with one channel per audio source

Tags: linux, audio-recording

I want to record a screencast under Linux in such way that the sound of my microphone is recorded on a separate channel than the sound of my speakers. Is there any tool which can do such screencast?

Comment: Do you want to use only one application or would two be ok?

Comment: I prefer using one application, but I can accept using two.

Comment: what applications have you used so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OBS-Studio - Open Broadcaster Software##

In [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) you can record pretty much any part of your screen or audio. You can choose options like window, screen etc for video and mic, speakers etc for audio.

By default these all go into the same channel but under Settings>Output you can choose advanced output mode which also allows for multiple audio channels. So you could choose 2 and set the channels accordingly.

[image: Settings]

right-click in Audio Mixer and choose 'Advanced Audio Properties'

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the tool which I need!
BTW, I think that the first of your two screenshots is wrong - it shows "streaming" tab, but in order to record a screencast one needs to use "recording" tab.